# Sort Map in Ascending Order by Key

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, map-function

I'm attempting to sort a Map in ascending order based on the keys. Given the `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

map.put(5, "five");
map.put(1, "one");
map.put(3, "three");
map.put(0, "zero");
```

I would like the order:

```
0, zero
1, one
3, three
5, five
```

I wrote the following code to accomplish this:

```
    public <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByKeyInAscendingOrder(Map<K, V> map)
{
    List<Entry<K, V>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    list.sort(Entry.comparingByKey());

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, when I call `sort()` I get the following error:

```
The method sort(Comparator<? super Map.Entry<K,V>>) in the type List<Map.Entry<K,V>> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<Map.Entry<Comparable<? super Comparable<? super K>>,Object>>)
```

I've written similar code (which works fine) to sort by value (changing `Entry.comparingByKey()` to `Entry.comparingByValue()` ) but for some reason when I try sorting by key I get the above error.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to make `K` comparable to sort by it; and the bound on `V` is wrong (but unnecessary anyway).

```
public <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> Map<K, V> sortByKeyInAscendingOrder(Map<K, V> map)
```

Mind you, an easier way might be:

```
return new LinkedHashMap<>(new TreeMap<>(map));
```

Or

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Entry.comparingKey())
    .collect(toMap(k -> k, v -> v, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: wow, so may great answers! You were the first to reply so I'm accepting this is the right answer.. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You can also try using java 8 streams

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    map.put(5, "five");
    map.put(1, "one");
    map.put(3, "three");
    map.put(0, "zero");

    map = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    System.out.println(map);  //{0=zero, 1=one, 3=three, 5=five}
```

Or you can use `forEach` on `Map`

```
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"  "+v));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [method `comparingByKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey()) requires its key, `K` type parameter, to be `Comparable`, not (necessarily) its value, `V`.

Move the bound `? extends Comparable<? super K>` from `V` to `K`.  Change

```
<K, V extends Comparable<? super K>>
```

to

```
<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

It is of course optional to have `V` be `Comparable` also, but make that bound refer to itself, not to `K`:

```
V extends Comparable<? super V>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a TreeMap? it keeps keys sorted in natural order:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

If you need to create it from an existing map, use it's parameterized constructor:

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(map);
```

because using a HashMap doesn't guarantee order and LinkedHashMap maintains insertion order. To keep map sorted by key, use TreeMap.